# How to install Ubuntu One Windows Beta on XP?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am trying to install the Ubuntu One Windows Beta program on Windows XP, but I keep getting the following error:

> "This installation package cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service. You must install a Windows service pack that contains a newer version of the Windows Installer service."

I have XP SP3 installed, and fully updated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need Windows Installer 4.5. This is covered in the Ubuntu One for Windows beta test FAQ which includes a link to download. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Windows#FAQ

Comment: Thanks for that :) I wonder how I missed that when I was looking before. I'll look harder next time.